# Implement a method that prints output without object-oriented support?

Tags: f#

Would I have to resort to F#'s object oriented design support to implement a method that returns void?

Specifically, what if I just wanted to print a message within a function?
Would I just have to create a member method within F# to accomplish this?

Example:

```
dealPlayer Hit {Face = Ace; Suit = Spades}
```

NOTE:
I am still learning F#. I'm apologize if this question appears ignorant.

```
type Suit = | Spades
            | Clubs
            | Diamonds
            | Hearts

type Face = | Two | Three | Four | Five 
            | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
            | Jack | Queen | King | Ace

type Card = {Face:Face; Suit:Suit}

type Deal = | Hand of Card * Card
            | Hit of Card

let dealPlayer dealType =
        match dealType with
        | Hand (card1, card2) ->  printfn "%A" (card1, card2)
        | Hit card -> printfn "%A" card

dealPlayer Hit {Face = Ace; Suit = Spades}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Functional_S answers, you can use `printfn`, but as a general observation, one of the main benefits of functional programming is to **avoid side-effects**.

Ultimately, all programs have side-effects, but the functional approach is to push the side-effects to the edge of whatever system you're building. (Incidentally, this is also true for most maintainable, successful object-oriented architectures; only you get less support from languages like C# or Java for doing that.)

So instead of letting `dealPlayer` have side-effects, make it a **pure function**:

```
let dealPlayer dealType =
    match dealType with
    | Hand (card1, card2) ->  sprintf "%A" (card1, card2)
    | Hit card -> sprintf "%A" card
```

This changes the type of the function to `Deal -> string`. (The name of the function may now be a bit misleading, though.)

At the edge of your system, you can still print the value if you want to, by piping the string to `printfn`:

```
> dealPlayer (Hit {Face = Ace; Suit = Spades}) |> printfn "%s";;
{Face = Ace;
 Suit = Spades;}
val it : unit = ()
```

That's much more flexible because you postpone the decision to introduce side-effects until such a time that you can no longer postpone it.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I was getting stuck on a compile error a little while ago. You also addressed that as well. Hence, I didn't know that I was required to wrap the argument inside parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, it print pretty well for small samples

```
let print x = printfn "%+A" x
```

Or if you need a return value

```
let toString x = sprintf "%+A" x
```